# PayPal Buttons. When Processed, Not Charging Taxes

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I've gone through the "Selling Tools" set-up process, but the taxes are still not showing up in the prices for my selling buttons (subscriptions or buy now).

I've copied and pasted this code into my button's HTML code as well, on my SquareSpace website, but to no avail:

Can you advise?

Answer (score 0):

The tax profile does not work with the subscription buttons, this would be available for your Buy Now or Shopping Cart buttons.

Prior to creating the buttons, you would need to set up the Tax Profile under Selling Tools.

1. Profile and Settings
2. Selling Tools
3. Sales Tax - Update
4. Create Tax Profile (Domestic/International)

Next is creating the button, when filling out the fields for the button you will need to select "Use saved values in PayPal profile" under Tax. This will enable the profile to check the customer's zip code.

When the customer pays, they would enter their PayPal Email/Password and the shipping calculation will auto populate once they select Log In.

Comment: I have already set up my tax profile, and knowbit works with the "shopping cart" and the "buy now", button. Do you know if the tax option is coming soon?

Comment: Not with the Standard PayPal buttons, I have not heard of this option becoming available any time soon.

Your other options would be to hard code Express Checkout to process the payment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ECDGRecurringPayments/

Or you would need to look for a 3rd Party Shopping cart that would support this. Here are some options: https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/shopping-carts